# single function for multiple range sliders

Tags: jquery, rangeslider

I have a page with multiple range sliders. I would like to control the output based on the value. Is there away to make this function work for multiple sliders on the same page? or do I have to re-write the function over again with new IDs for each input?

Code:

```css
$(".slider").mousemove(function () {
  if ($(this).val()==this.min) {
    $(".priceOutputId").text("Less than $80")
  }
  else if ($(this).val()==this.max) {
    $(".priceOutputId").text("More than $100")
  }
  else {
    $(".priceOutputId").text("around $" + $(this).val())
  }
}

)
```

```html
<label class="radio_title">
  <input type="range" min="80" max="100" value="80" class="slider" id="priceInputId">
  <div class="range_output">
    <output name="priceOutputName" class="priceOutputId">Less Than $80</output>
  </div>
</label>

<label class="radio_title">
  <input type="range" min="80" max="100" value="80" class="slider" id="priceInputId">
  <div class="range_output">
    <output name="priceOutputName" class="priceOutputId">Less Than $80</output>
  </div>
</label>
```

Comment: yes, it is possible to use a single function, but what issues are you having? Where did you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the output relevant to only the element which raised the event you need to hook the logic to the `this` reference. From there you can use jQuery's DOM traversal methods, such as `closest()` and `find()` to retrieve the relevant elements and update them.

Also note that you cannot use the same `id` attribute multiple times. They must be unique. If you want to group elements by behaviour use a `class`. In addition, the `input` event is more appropriate for a range slider control, as it also works when the controls value is changed via the keyboard.

With all that said, try this:

```js
$(".slider").on('input', function() {
  let $label = $(this).closest('label');  
  let $output = $label.find('.priceOutput');

  if (this.value == this.min) {
    $output.text("Less than $80")
  } else if (this.value == this.max) {
    $output.text("More than $100")
  } else {
    $output.text("around $" + this.value)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="radio_title">
  <input type="range" min="80" max="100" value="80" class="slider priceInput">
  <div class="range_output">
    <output name="priceOutputName" class="priceOutput">Less Than $80</output>
  </div>
</label>

<label class="radio_title">
  <input type="range" min="80" max="100" value="80" class="slider priceInputId">
  <div class="range_output">
    <output name="priceOutputName" class="priceOutput">Less Than $80</output>
  </div>
</label>
```

Also note that the `if` condition can be shortened using the following ternary. I'll leave it to your choice whether you prefer the brevity over the ease of reading:

```
let output = this.value === this.min ? 'Less than $80' : this.value === this.max ? 'More than $100' : 'Around $' + this.value;
$output.text(output);
```

Comment: Wow, Thanks so much. Exactly what I need, and I understand what was done. I love this place.

Comment: No problem, glad to help